# appending a numpy array but organising the appended information in two dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, text, split

This feels as if it should be super easy but I am struggling.

I have some code that just reads a text file. The text file is annoyingly complicated but basically is has three rotation angles in it and looks something like this:

```
HeaderInformation

datalocation    sometext     1    3.45   15.5    -120
datalocation2    sometext2     1    5.4   125    -140
```

So I currently have the code:

```
data = textfile.readlines
variable = 'datalocation'
Rotations = np.array([])
for line in data:
    if variable in line:
        linesplit = line.split()
        AngleRot = linesplit[3]
        AngleTilt = linesplit[4]
        AnglePsi = linesplit[5]
        Rotations = np.append(Rotations, ([AngleRot], [AngleTilt], [AnglePsi]))

print RelionRotations
```

This works but all the angles are just added to the numpy array one after the other.

I need to use these angles later for calculations but I want them split up so I can grab out the rotations of each line in the text file. i.e I want them indexed as 3 values per line in a 2D numpy array.

This seems like it should be easy but I am struggling to figure out now to do it.

Comment: `numpy` csv readers like `genfromtxt` create a list of lists from the lines, and then create the array at the end.  `usecols` and `skiprows` can be used to control which values are parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
# skiprow: skip your header information
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=r"\s+", skiprows=range(1, 2), header=None)
your_array = df[[2,3,4,5]].values # your numpy array
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. If I were to have no spaces between the data and instead just underscores would there also be a way to do this. I.e would it ready like: Xrotation20_Yrotation-3_Zrotation_50.

Comment: Yes, just  use `delimiter='_'` or `sep='_'`, these two are the same thing.

Comment: Yeah that works for splitting it all up initially but to grab out the actual numbers whatever I try either just gives me text with no numbers (trying \d+)

Comment: Oh I see. yes. That'll be tricky -- Maybe try rewriting the csv first before loading it in? Because you can do regex grep numbers in string operation but not when you're reading a `csv`.

Comment: Hmm thankfully I create that text file myself in an earlier bit of processing so I will just put an '_' before and after each number. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With numpy's own csv reader

```
In [29]: txt = '''HeaderInformation
    ...: 
    ...: datalocation    sometext     1    3.45   15.5    -120
    ...: datalocation2    sometext2     1    5.4   125    -140'''

In [32]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),skip_header=2)
In [33]: data
Out[33]: 
array([[    nan,     nan,    1.  ,    3.45,   15.5 , -120.  ],
       [    nan,     nan,    1.  ,    5.4 ,  125.  , -140.  ]])
```

Or skipping the 2 text columns:

```
In [34]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),skip_header=2,usecols=[2,3,4,5])
In [35]: data
Out[35]: 
array([[   1.  ,    3.45,   15.5 , -120.  ],
       [   1.  ,    5.4 ,  125.  , -140.  ]])
```